# java event handler wait before piece of code is run

Tags: java, multithreading, event-handling

I searched for my question but I didn't find anything similar... I have an event handler for new data received from serial port. and when a complete packet is received a function (big function) executes which updates the UI and so on. the problem is sometimes before ending that code, new data arrives and again process goes from start and UI won't be updates real time...
I want a method that keeps event handler waiting until the specific function is executed,then event handler triggers and again...
this is the code, event handler for data receiving

```
 StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
        //scanner = new Scanner(Selected.getInputStream());
 Selected.addDataListener(new SerialPortDataListener() {@Override
public int getListeningEvents() { return SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_AVAILABLE; }
   @Override
   public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event){if (event.getEventType() != SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_AVAILABLE)
     return;
        byte[] newData = new byte[Selected.bytesAvailable()];
  int numRead = Selected.readBytes(newData, newData.length);
  for(int i =0 ; i<newData.length;i++){
      temp.append((char) newData[i]);
      if((char) newData[i] == '\n'){
       logText.appendText(temp.toString());
          if(tele.checkSumCheck(temp.toString())){
             if(exportCSV){
             writeToCSV(temp.toString());
             }
            System.out.println(temp.toString());
            tele.initString(temp.toString());
            tele.parseString();
            updateUI();
      }
            temp.setLength(0);
      }
```

I think it can be solved with multithreading ... the problem is when new data arrives the telemetry packet changes so I don't know what happens in different threads in that case... in that case we have still a last telemetry data that is being displayed and updating the UI with that and new data that has just arrived.

Comment: You could potentially queue the various events and process them as they come in. For example you could have a queue where events are store, which is then polled by a thread which takes up the job of processing them.

This way you should be able to guarantee that events are processed one by one (serial) and the UI is updated as each processing action is completed.

Comment: can you please suggest me some keywords or give me more detail of how can I do that? I am not familiar with this concept

Comment: Have you tried a Reactive programming, like ReactiveRX? It's specifically meant for situations like this, where the code is event based, including "data received" events and "data processed" events.

Comment: I haven't heard reactiveRX..can u give me quick beginner reference that I can start with?